# Raspberry Pi Flask server does not work with SQLite data when running code

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, raspberry-pi, gpio

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

I am following the tutorial here:
https://medium.com/@rovai/from-data-to-graph-a-web-jorney-with-flask-and-sqlite-6c2ec9c0ad0

The data is stored correctly, but when setting up and running the Flask server it gives the error:

```
$ sudo python3 appDhtWebServer.py 

 * Serving Flask app "appDhtWebServer" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "appDhtWebServer.py", line 41, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 814, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 774, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 660, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 577, in __init__
    self.address_family), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

The main Flask code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
import sqlite3
# Retrieve data from database
def getData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('../sensorsData.db')
    curs=conn.cursor()
    for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM DHT_data ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"):
        time = str(row[0])
        temp = row[1]
        hum = row[2]
    conn.close()
    return time, temp, hum
# main route 
@app.route("/")
def index():    
    time, temp, hum = getData()
    templateData = {'time': time,'temp': temp,'hum': hum}
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=False)
```

The index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>DHT Sensor data </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href='../static/style.css'/>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>DHT Sensor Data </h1>
    <h3> TEMPERATURE   ==>  {{ tempLab  }} oC</h3>
    <h3> HUMIDITY (Rel.) ==>  {{ humLab  }} %</h3>
    <hr>
    <h3> Last Sensors Reading: {{ time }} ==> <a href="/"class="button">REFRESH</a></h3>    
    <hr>
    <p> @2018 Developed by MJRoBot.org</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

The style.css:

```
body{
    background: blue;
    color: yellow;
    padding:1%
}
.button {
    font: bold 15px Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: There's something running on port 80 already.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly states that port 80 is already in use.

Either another app is running on port 80 or you run Flask twice. Check all your terminal windows.

You also could use `lsof` or `netstat` or `ss` to find out which program runs on port 80.